# Views Filter Content Type Drop down option sorting

Tags: views

I have a view to with the Filter of Content Type in drop down and based on selection it is displaying the nodes.

Now I need to alphabetically order the Content Type options into Filter Drop down.

Currently the content type listed into drop down as

- Press Release
- News
- Event

and I need to display it as

- Event
- News
- Press Release

There is no such way I found into views configuration. Do any one have idea how to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

One solution here is to use the `Grouped filters` option the `Filter type to expose` setting. In each grouped filter you can use the Is one of... operator and select the type. Grouped filters have weights that you can drag around to any arbitrary ordering.

As an example, here's a reverse ordering of content types:

[image]

[image]